# Mongoose pre(validate) doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to save a real date to DB from this date string.I've done this before with another matter and it worked fine.Just couldnt figure out whats wrong. this.date prints this kinda string in MongoDB. "date" : "4/20/2018", It also gets the default into realDate.Plus I dont get the console.log either

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var attendanceSchema = new Schema({
  date: String,
  absent: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  realDate: { type: Date, default: new Date() }
});

attendanceSchema.pre("validate", function(next) {
  var newDate = this.date;
  this.realDate = new Date(newDate);
  console.log("done");

  next();
});

var Atten = mongoose.model("Attendance", attendanceSchema);

module.exports = Atten;
```

Comment: You have `date: String` in your schema, so no matter what you do this is what it will be converted to. Simply `date: Date` will do the correct casting. Or are you actually asking how to fix your existing data where this is already stored as strings?

Comment: Also `"4/20/2018"` is not an ISO format, so it will not convert correctly. It's likely going to presume "local time" before converting to UTC.

Comment: i need both of these in the DB.As a string and  as a date.So i get the string date.and using it to create a date just before saving it to DB and assign it to another field names realDate.

Comment: @NeilLunn I used w3schools and inserted in their try it editor,The date converted just fine.